# Make spring security form login return 403 code with java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Form based security is redirection to the login page if a user is not authenticated and tries to access a protected action. Instead of the redirect I want it to return HTTP code 403.

As far as I understand, I have to register some kind of entry point for this. Unfortunately I don't undertand how I can set this up for a java based configuration.

This is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
pubfooc class FOOSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    //@formatter:off
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(aS400AuthenticationProvider())
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authorized")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .usernameParameter("cfooentId")
                .successHandler(foorAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(foorAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(foorRememberMeServices())
                .key(CookieService.FOO_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPofoocy(SessionCreationPofoocy.STATELESS)
            ;
    }
    //@formatter:on

    @Bean
    pubfooc FOORememberMeServices foorRememberMeServices() {
        return new FOORememberMeServices();
    }

    @Bean
    pubfooc AS400AuthenticationProvider aS400AuthenticationProvider() {
        return new AS400AuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    pubfooc CookieService cookieService() {
        return new CookieService.Impl();
    }

    @Bean
    pubfooc FOOAuthenticationSuccessHandler foorAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new FOOAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    pubfooc FOOAuthenticationFailureHandler foorAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new FOOAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())` (assuming you are using Spring Security 2.0 or higher).